# VBscript get parameters from Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, vbscript

I need your help in the following situation:
I'm developing an app with a Sql Server 2008 db in back-end.
 I want to store some URL's in the database and I put a button in my interface which should open these URL's.

I want to code the button in VBscript but I'm a newbie in this language.

I found this code `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "\\195.234.22\server\docs"` which works fine but I want to take the links from the database, I suppose that I should set some parameters but I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a basic example of connecting to SQL Server [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125474/vbscript-to-connect-to-sql-server-2005-and-update-a-table), although it's for an `UPDATE` instead of a `SELECT`. There are plenty of examples of connecting to SQL Server from VBScript on the web, so it might be good if you can be more precise about what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the way forward is to write a stored procedure to return the date you want from the database, then bind this to a grid template, you can then select the column control type as an html link. You'll get a lot of extra goodies thrown in.