# SQL Server: The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context / windows authentication for the login

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, connection-string, sspi, security-context

I saw a couple of other questions like this one but no one could solve my issue.

I have a SQL 2016 Express and a database `mydatabase`. I created a login using `Windows Authentication` and I used my AD user `domain\myuser`. In `mydatabase` -> security -> Users I created a user called `myuser` (User type = Windows user, Login name = `domain\myuser`). Default Schema is dbo and in the Securables menu I added `mytable` and gave the following rights: Alter, Delete, Insert, Select and Update.

If I open SQL Management Studio as `domain\myuser`, connect to that SQL server, run `use mydatabase` and `select * from mytable`, everything works fine.

Now, using a vbscript, from a command prompt running as `domain\myuser`, it will fail. The relevant part of the `myscript.vbs` script is this:

```
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Server=myserver\myinstance;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Set cxn = Wscript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cxn.Open strConn
cxn.CommandTimeout = 0 
strSqlQuery = "use mydatabase"
Set rs=cxn.Execute(strSqlQuery)
```

This will fail with:

```
myscript.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server:
The server principal "domain\myuser" is not able to access the
database "mydatabase" under the current security context.
```

I tried to add the `database=mydatabase` in the SQL connection string but it didn´t work either.

Looking at some of the answers in other questions, some people asked to run the following command in the SQL Management Studio:

```
sp_change_users_login  @Action='Report';
```

It was not clear if that was with a db_owner or the affected user, so I ran with both. With the db_owner the result was the columns `UserName` and `UserSID` empty, whereas with `domain\myuser` it said:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 51 [Batch Start Line 10]
User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Is my `Integrated Security` part in my script connection string wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you running this script on a website?

Comment: No, I´m running directly on the server where the database is.

Comment: Okay. Just wanted to make sure that IIS, Application pools, etc. We're not involved. You may want to reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125474/vbscript-to-connect-to-sql-server-2005-and-update-a-table

Comment: It's likely a UAC issue in terms of both the SQL Server and the context of the VBScript execution.

Comment: @S.Walker, apparently I should be using SQLOLEDB.1 instead of SQLOLEDB in the connection string for my Integrated Security to work. Your article led me to the resolution. If you post as a reply I can choose as the answer. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

For my case when I go into depth, I have found that users have super rights on SQL Server & on MSDB are working fine.

Reason in my case: CONNECT permissions are denied from PUBLIC role.

2 possible solutions:
1. Provide connect permissions to all user sepratly
2. Provide CONNECT permission to PUBLIC role

Comment: The issue was the connection string. I mentioned in the comment in 2017. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set permission at the database level.
to do so follow the steps:

1. Right-click on the desired database (MyDB)
2. Choose "Properties" from the popup menu
3. From the left menu choose "Permissions"
4. Checked required permission only

[image]

Comment: My question was from 2017 and I don’t work with MS SQL server anymore. But from what I can see your answer is very dangerous as it suggests to give full access to the public. Not what I wanted at all. On the other hand. In 2017 I posted a comment that I found the issue. It was in my connection string. The guy that provided the link never posted it as an answer so this question remained forever unsolved.